# Efficiently list a few directories among many with rclone filtering

Tags: rclone

Running the following produces a quick listing of a directory with e.g. 10 objects:

```bash
$ rclone ls s3:bucket/dir1/
...
```

In an attempt to perform some other operation (besides listing) on the objects in this and one or two other directories, I'm using a `filter-file.txt` (for documentation, see [Rclone Filtering](https://rclone.org/filtering/)):

```
+ /dir1/**
+ /dir2/**
- **
```

And then running:

```
rclone --dump filters -vv ls s3:bucket --filter-from filter-file.txt
...
```

Because the `/bucket/` has many other directories in it, however, this takes much longer.

It seems like the [directory filter](https://rclone.org/filtering/#directory_filter) section would have some answers, but my assumption at the moment is it can't help this situation. My assumption: because the `/bucket/` directory is a parent directory of `dir1`, there will always be a directory filter to include `/bucket/` and everything in it will have to be matched against the first two `+` filters. Is that correct? Is there a workaround anyone is aware of to get faster behavior like the original `ls` above (besides calling rclone two times)?

Answer (score 0):

See [Efficiently list a few directories among many with rclone filtering - Help and Support - rclone forum](https://forum.rclone.org/t/efficiently-list-a-few-directories-among-many-with-rclone-filtering/36786/3) for a detailed answer from `asdffdsa` and `ncw`. To over-summarize:

> The rclone filters don't have the level of optimisation so that it can avoid listing /bucket/ though it is completely obvious to you and me that it doesn't need to.
>
> I think you will have to run two rclone ls commands one for each directory if you wish to avoid listing the root.